# How to work with a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, foreach, mysqli

Here is a var_dump or an array returned from my MODEL:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[19]
          public 'X_SIZE' => string '1.75x3' (length=6)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[20]
          public 'X_SIZE' => string '1.75x3.5(slim)' (length=14)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[21]
          public 'X_SIZE' => string '2x3' (length=3)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[17]
          public 'X_PAPER' => string '14ptGlossCoatedCoverwithUV(C2S)' (length=31)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[18]
          public 'X_PAPER' => string '14ptPremiumUncoatedCover' (length=24)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[24]
          public 'X_PAPER' => string '16ptDullCoverwithMatteFinish' (length=28)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[23]
          public 'X_COLOR' => string '1000' (length=4)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[22]
          public 'X_COLOR' => string '1002' (length=4)
  3 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[26]
          public 'X_QTY' => string '100' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[25]
          public 'X_QTY' => string '250' (length=3)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[29]
          public 'X_QTY' => string '500' (length=3)
      3 => 
        object(stdClass)[30]
          public 'X_QTY' => string '1000' (length=4)
  4 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[28]
          public 'O_RC' => string 'YES' (length=3)
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[27]
          public 'O_RC' => string 'NO' (length=2)
      2 => 
        object(stdClass)[33]
          public 'O_RC' => string 'NA' (length=2)
```

My controller is sending to my view and on my view the above dump is of: `var_dump($printerOptions)`

Ok so I need to create a dropdown menu for each of these arrays and radio buttons for the `O_RC` array.

I am using codeigniter and using `form_dropdown('',$val);` inside of a foreach loop causes multiple dropdowns for each key and element in the array.

```
foreach ($printerOptions as $Options) 
{
//var_dump($Options);
    foreach ($Options as $Specs) 
    {
        echo $Specs->X_SIZE;
        echo $Specs->X_PAPER;
        echo $Specs->X_COLOR;
        echo $Specs->X_QTY;
        echo $Specs->O_RC;
    }
}
```

This ^ code will echo out the expected values of the corresponding arrays but for some reason I get LOOPING errors with the output:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$X_PAPER
Undefined property: stdClass::$X_COLOR
Undefined property: stdClass::$X_QTY
Undefined property: stdClass::$O_RC
```

Looking at my array how can I create a dropdown menu for each of the arrays respectively?

Thanks for the help.

## MODEL /// Update ///

```
class M_Pricing extends CI_Model {

    function get_prices() 
    {
        $table_by_product = 'printer_businesscards'; //replace with URI Segment
        
        //Get all the columns in the table set by the page URI of $table_by_product variable 
        $get_all_col_names = $this->db->list_fields($table_by_product);
        
        //Loop through the column names. All names starting with 'O_' are optional fields for the 
        //current product. Get all Distinct values and create a radio button list in form.
        $resultArray = array();
        
        foreach ($get_all_col_names as $key => $value) {
            //get all o_types for the product by column name
            if (preg_match('/O_/', $value)) 
                {
                $v = (array('Specs' => $value));
                foreach ($v as $vals) {
                    $this->db->select($vals);
                    $this->db->distinct();
                    $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product);
                    $resultArray[] = $qX->result();
                    }
                } 
            
            //Get all x_types for the product by column name. All 'X_' types are specific product options.
            //Create a dropdown menu with all DISTINCT product options. 
            if (preg_match('/X_/', $value)) 
                {
                $v = (array('Type' => $value));
                foreach ($v as $vals) {
                    $this->db->select($vals);
                    $this->db->distinct();
                    $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product);
                    $resultArray[] = $qX->result();
                    }
                }       
        }
        //return $resultArray
        //var_dump($resultArray); die;
        return $resultArray;
    }
```

Comment: @Aziz thanks for the edit.. How about an answer or some help? ;)

Comment: You don't have single objects containing all those properties -- you have arrays of objects each having a _single_ property. They can't be related though, because there isn't a consistent number of objects per array. For example, you have only 2 of `X_COLOR`, but you have 3 `X_PAPER`.  How are these related?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski thanks for your input I notice the array isn't as it should be to properly loop through the values. If I post my MODEL code can you help my make the proper modifications so that I can have a FOREACH I'll be able to iterate through on my VIEW -- Thanks! :)

Comment: I'll have a look if you post it

Comment: @fabio, you can loop throught your inner array `foreach $Options as $option)` , or change your array to be array of objects, last is preffered as it seems you turn that array incorrect side

Comment: @eicto I can't exactly loop through and I'm not sure I know what you mean by change to an array or objects. Please take a look at my model and I welcome your help. Thanks.

Comment: you should setup array different, do it as array of product_options but not options, i can't place this as answer because it will not be answer i think.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski so do you have any suggestions :) ?

Comment: @fabio I'm sorry I don't have a good sense of what your `select()` statements in the loops are returning

Comment: [let's continue in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19001/eicto-fabio-chat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understand your result array should be object or hash and look  like:

```
array('Type'=>array(
   'X_SIZE'=>array('1.75x3','1.75x3.5(slim)','2x3'),
   'X_PAPER'=>array('14ptGlossCoatedCoverwithUV(C2S)','14ptPremiumUncoatedCover'),
///...),
'Specs'=>array(
```

//...)
    );

to loop through such structure:

```
//Types
echo 'Types';
foreach ($Options['Types'] as $type=>$values) {
echo $type;
echo "<select>";
foreach ($values as $value) {
echo "<option value="$value">$value</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}

//Specs
echo 'Specs';
foreach ($Options['Specs'] as $type=>$values) {
 echo $type;
 echo "<select>";
 foreach ($values as $value) {
   echo "<option value="$value">$value</option>";
 }
 echo "</select>";
}
```

model:

```
<?php
class M_Pricing extends CI_Model {

    function get_prices() 
    {
        $table_by_product = 'printer_businesscards'; //replace with URI Segment

        //Get all the columns in the table set by the page URI of $table_by_product variable 
        $get_all_col_names = $this->db->list_fields($table_by_product);

        //Loop through the column names. All names starting with 'O_' are optional fields for the 
        //current product. Get all Distinct values and create a radio button list in form.

        $resultArray=array();
        $resultArray['Options']=array();
        $resultArray['Specs']=array();

        foreach ($get_all_col_names as $key => $value) {
            //get all o_types for the product by column name
            $opt_type="";
            if (preg_match('/O_/', $value)) {$opt_type="Options";} elseif
               (preg_match('/X_/', $value)) {$opt_type="Specs";} else {continue;}
               if (!isset($resultArray[$opt_type][$value])) {$resultArray[$opt_type][$value]=array();}
                    $this->db->select($value);
                    $this->db->distinct();
                    $qX = $this->db->get($table_by_product);
                    foreach ($qX->result() as $v) {
                     $resultArray[$opt_type][$value][]=$v->$value;
                    }
           }      

        //return $resultArray
        //var_dump($resultArray); die;
        return $resultArray;
    }
}
```